# sending image to another activity

Tags: android

I am trying to send an image that in ListView from onItemClick to onCreate method in another activity .

This is my code :

**Activity 1**

```
product_imageView= findViewById(R.id.product_imageView);


byte[] image = savedInstanceState.getByteArray("Product image");

 Bitmap receivedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);

//here it give me error
        product_imageView.setImageResource(receivedImage);
```

**Activity 1**

```
String productimage = productslist.get(position).getProductImage();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putByteArray("Product image", productimage.getBytes());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the amount of bytes one can put into a `Bundle` is limited. better pass the productId.

Comment: how can i do that ? can you provide code

Comment: `bundle.putInt("productId", productslist.get(position).getProductId());`

Comment: save your bitmap in a separate file on storage and pass path uri between activities.

Comment: You might get `TransactionTooLarge` exception if bitmap is large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

**First convert imageview to bitmap.**

```
product_imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = product_imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

In second Activity please include this line:

```
  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");

  imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending images between activities?, why not just place your image in drawable folder and pass the name or path of the image to the next activity and then display or do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this

1. put your image in drawable folder for example image1.png.
2. then all you do is parse a string with the name for the image to the second activity example:

> ```
>    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
>                 intent.putExtra("image", "image1.png");
>                 startActivity(intent);
> ```

3. On the second activity you display for instance:

> ```
>   Intent intent = getIntent();
>   String imageStr = intent.getStringExtra("image");
>   ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage);
>   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
> ```

I hope code is correct, forgive my mistakes I wrote this in a hurry.